# FOREIGN KEY constraint on key with existing record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm attempting to build up a database to reference from a separate application. I've added several tables including `dbo.Quest`, `dbo.Series` and `dbo.QuestSeries`.

These are the table definitions, for reference:

**dbo.Quest**

```
ID (PK, int, not null)
Name (varchar(255), not null)
QuestPoints (int, not null)
Members (bit, not null)
Difficulty (FK, int, null)
Length (FK, int null)
Age (FK, int, null)
Miniquest (bit, null)
```

**dbo.Series**

```
ID (PK, int, not null)
Name (varchar(50), null)
```

**dbo.QuestSeries**

```
ID (PK, int, not null)
Quest (FK, int, null)
Series (FK, int, null)
```

I'm attempting to run an `INSERT` into `dbo.QuestSeries` and I get the following error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__QuestSeri__Serie__4CA06362". The conflict occurred in database "RunescapeLogger", table "dbo.Quest", column 'ID'.

My understanding is that it would indicate that I have some IDs missing from the `dbo.Quest` table that I'm trying to insert into `dbo.QuestSeries`, but I've triple-checked and all of the IDs I'm entering exist in both the `dbo.Quest` and the `dbo.Series` tables.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You need to **AT LEAST** show us **(1)** the FK constraints as defined on your tables, **(2)** the data in `dbo.Quest`, and **(3)** the `INSERT` statement you're using. So far, we can only be guessing....

Comment: Random guess, the rows in the Quest table are in a transaction that hasn't been committed.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you correctly define foreign key and it respectively columns. Here is sample which may refer. It works perfectly.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Checking the foreign key caused me to find the issue.  FK_QuestSeri_Serie_4CA06362 was referencing dbo.Quest.ID instead of dbo.Series.ID.  I was able to drop the key and correctly create a new one.